# In thermodynamic identity, dU=TdS-PdV. Are dS and dV orthogonal or is (T,P) defined in a conjugated space from (dS,dV)?

Tags: thermodynamics, maxwell-relations

In thermodynamic identity, we say dU=TdS-pdV, and only Maxwell's relation is required for U to be a proper behaved thermodynamics variable.

But from multivariable calculus, that result requires dS and dV to be orthogonal to each other. And I never see people prove that or trying to justify the Maxwell's relation otherwise. My guess is that the vector field (T,P) is defined in a conjugated space, so that dS, dV is no longer required to be orthogonal. But I don't have reliable reference to justify if my guess is canonical or not. Anyone knows it?

Comment: There is no orthogonality implied anywhere without a metric even in multivariable calculus and there is no meaningful metric in thermodstatics in the conventional sense. The "identity" $dU=TdS-pdV$ is true for any differentiable function of two variable $U=U(S,V)$. The "physics" there is the meaning of the partial derivatives $\frac {\partial U}{\partial S}$ and $\frac {\partial U}{\partial V}$ and for that you need Carnot, Clausius, Gibbs, Kelvin, etc,

Comment: No, there isn't orthgonality implied anywhere. That's why we need to be careful when utilising multivariable calculus to obtain Maxwell's relation. And defining vector field on conjugated space is one solution. On the other hand, by defining $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}|_V$, we already assumed that vector $T\hat{e^1}$ is orthogonal to $V\hat{e_2}$. Thus I think defining (T,P) on conjugated space is the solution used. I'm just not certain about it.